# I am unable to install express

Tags: node.js, express, installation-package

I have window 7 64 bit and installed node version 5.9.1 and npm version 3.7.3 but I am unable to install express in my htdocs/game folder using cmd

Comment: This question is full of details but entirely bereft of useful ones. :) What is the specific error you are getting? How did you try to install it?

Comment: "I am unable to install express" is the extent of your question? Nope.